# out Parameter used with [ref] in PowerShell are not filled

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to call the Copy.asmx WebService of SharePoint from a PowerShell Script:

```
$copyWS = .\Connect-WebService.ps1 $copyWsdlUrl -requiresAuthentication
$copyWS.UseDefaultCredentials = $true

[FieldInformation[]]$fieldInfos = $null
[System.Byte[]]$data = $null
$copyWS.GetItem($fileUrl, [ref]$fieldInfos, [ref]$data)
```

Result: GetItem returns 0 for success, but $fieldInfos and $data are $null. If I do the same thing from a C# Console Application, it works fine and data.Length equals my file length.

```
Copy copyWS = new Copy();
copyWS.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

FieldInformation[] fieldInfos = null;
byte[] data = null;
uint result = copyWS.GetItem(fileUrl, out fieldInfos, out data);

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
```

Where is my mistake or is this a PowerShell bug?

Following beefarino's advice I called $copyWS.GetItem and got:

```
System.UInt32 GetItem(string Url,
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3http___moss__vti_bin_Copy_asmx.FieldInformation[]&, jfww_71i, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Fields,
System.Byte[]&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Stream)
```

So my parameters look right, I even changed the type of $fieldInfos to display the full name `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3http___moss__vti_bin_Copy_asmx.FieldInformation[]` but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that connect-webservice.ps1 ends up invoking new-webserviceproxy...

Verify the signature of the web service method from powershell using get-member:

`$copyWS | get-member`

or by dumping the method to the host without invoking it:

`$copyWS.GetItem`

The proxies don't always look as you'd expect; e.g., for this method:

`int GetData(out byte[] value);`

the new-webserviceproxy method generated by powershell looks like this:

`void GetData([ref] $result, [ref] $resultSpecified, [ref] $value)`

Comment: Good point, for $copyWS.GetItem I get: System.UInt32 GetItem(string Url, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3http___moss__vti_bin_Copy_asmx.FieldInformation[]&, jfww_71i, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Fields, System.Byte[]&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Stream)

Comment: So my usage seems correct (see the edit of my question) ... any other advice?

Comment: Yes - this is a crap shoot though.  Try removing the type specifiers from your variable declarations.  Not sure why I'm thinking this, but I know PowerShell can be hinky when dealing with types.

Comment: It works!!! I changed it to: $fieldInfos = $null $data = $null $copyWS.GetItem($fileUrl, [ref]$fieldInfos, [ref]$data) and it works. If you edit this into your answer, I will accept it. Thanks a lot!!!